# Do 64gb and 128gb SDXC cards work on the Macbook Air 2011?

Tags: macbook-pro, sd-card

I'm considering getting a [SDXC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#SDXC) card to extend the drive space of my Macbook Air. I just want to make sure both the 64 GB and 128 GB SDXC cards work on the 2011 Macbook Air.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears to work according to several reports:

http://www.zdnet.co.uk/reviews/ultraportables/2011/07/26/apple-macbook-air-2011-133in-40093522/

> There has been some concern that Apple lists the MacBook Pro models on
>   its web site as having an SDXC card slot, for high-capacity SD cards,
>   and only lists the card reader on the Air as an SD card one. We tried
>   a 64GB SanDisk SDXC card in the MacBook Air's card reader, and the
>   system recognised it as the appropriate size and was able to access
>   files on it. However, if you're looking to get a massive SD card in
>   order to augment the smallish 128GB SSD built into the Air, note that
>   the card slot leaves the SD card hanging halfway out on the side of
>   the system, so it's not appropriate for full-time use.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3014714?start=0&tstart=0

> I got my Transcend SDXC 64GB flash card, and yes, it reads and writes
>   perfectly in my MacBook Air.

[According to iFixit](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook-Air-13-Inch-Mid-2011-Teardown/6130/2) it uses the [Gensys logic GL822 SD slot controller](http://www.genesyslogic.com/_en/product_01_1.php?id=79) which is a USB 2.0 high speed device (480mbps) and supports up to 2TB SDXC cards.

Answer (score 3):

According to this [discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3014714?start=0&tstart=0) on Apple's forums, both 64 and 128 GB SDXC cards are well supported on the latest [mid-2011 at the time of writing] MBA, provided you format them using the Mac OS X Journaled option.

Answer (score 1):

My mid-2011 MacBook Air recognizes and uses a Komputerbay 64 GB SDXC card just fine. It's a $54 card from [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008AN1DHI). However, I only get read speeds around 33 MB/s from this card.

the card reader is on a USB 2 bus so it will never be all that fast.  As some point they put the card reader on a ?pci-e? bus and it has higher possible speed.